# Merge function messes up the data order

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a set of pairs of origin and destination points in `df1`. I would like to add columns to this data with a) attributes of `Orig` from `df2`. Then I would like to add attributes to the `Dest` column from `df3`. The problem is that the order of `df1` gets rearranged and this is not my intention. My question is how to keep the order of the rows constant in the final output without the need to add an extra column at the beginning with ID, which I could later on sort?

Original table:

```
  Orig Dest
1    a    b
2    b    e
3    c    a
4    b    c
5    a    b
6    c    a
7    e    b

Orig = c("a","b","c","b","a","c","e")
Dest = c("b","e","a","c","b","a","b")

df1 = data.frame(Orig,Dest)

Code <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
Name <- c("Ams","Bir","Cas","Das","Ees")
Lat <- c(4,6,7,3,2)
Long <- c(13,45,63,43,23)
df2 <- data.frame(Code,Name,Lat,Long)
df3 <- data.frame(Code,Name,Lat,Long)
colnames(df2) <- c("Orig","Name","Lat","Long")
colnames(df3) <- c("Dest","Name","Lat","Long")

Result1 <- merge(df1,df2,by = c("Orig"), sort=FALSE) # tried without sort as well
Result2 <- merge(Result1,df3,by = c("Dest"), sort=FALSE)
```

My current outcome

```
  Dest Orig Name.x Lat.x Long.x Name.y Lat.y Long.y
1    b    a    Ams     4     13    Bir     6     45
2    b    a    Ams     4     13    Bir     6     45
3    b    e    Ees     2     23    Bir     6     45
4    e    b    Bir     6     45    Ees     2     23
5    c    b    Bir     6     45    Cas     7     63
6    a    c    Cas     7     63    Ams     4     13
7    a    c    Cas     7     63    Ams     4     13
```

Desired outcome:

```
  Orig Dest Name.x Lat.x Long.x Name.y Lat.y Long.y
1    a    b    Ams     4     13    Bir     6     45
2    b    e    Bir     6     45    Ees     2     23
3    c    a    Cas     7     63    Ams     4     13
4    b    c    Bir     6     45    Cas     7     63
5    a    b    Ams     4     13    Bir     6     45
6    c    a    Cas     7     63    Ams     4     13
7    e    b    Ees     2     23    Bir     6     45
```

Comment: You say you want to add attributes of `Orig` from `df2`. Is your current outcome undesired in that `Bir` is matched to `a` from `Orig`? Or do you really want to match the attributes to `Dest`, but keep the line order of the resulting dataframe based on `Orig`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is here. Also, did you mean to tag this question with the data.table package? It doesn't come up in the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I edited the question hope it is more clear this time. I added data.table as I dont know the package but I know it can do nice work with data (I put request originally for alternative functions). Sorry if it doesn't go with SO ethics, I removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

So depending on if you want the Attributes to match Orig or Dest, just change this up, but you can sort the attributes from `df2` by either Orig or Dest:

```
df2[charmatch(Orig,Code),]
```

and then add back in the Dest/Orig column from df1